# JavaFX ComboBox with TreeView

Tags: combobox, treeview, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a ComboBox with a TreeView.
So that when I select the combobox I see an expanded Tree like along the lines of this;

[Manufacturer] <- Root node (may or may not be visible),
- Apple
-- iPhone
-- iPad
- Microsoft
-- Surface Pro
-- Office

I'm somewhat at a loss as to how to implement this. I've gotten a TreeView to display in a ListCell.
However there is one tree for each "item" in comboBox.getItems() and I can't get the selection to show in the combobox.

Editing is not required, just displaying and of course selection.

So I'm looking for any pointers as to how to implement this in a semi-sane way.

Comment: I haven't worked much with `TreeView`, but can't you get the selection from it and bind that to your `ComboBox`? This would allow you to use only one tree as the first item of your combo box but still retain the appearance and general functionality of a `ComboBox`.

Comment: The problem with that approach, as far as I got with it anyway, is that I can't get the selected node (it's text) to be displayed when the combobox is in it's "inert" state. Otherwise the tree remembers it's selection and "all is good". I've tried mucking about with setGraphic(null) and setText("nodetext"). But setText("...") just displays when the combobox is activated.

Comment: What if you used a label or button to show/hide a tree (possibly contained within its own hierarchy)? You can bind the label/button text to the text of the selected item in the tree.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I've ended up pursing. There are of course some issues regarding getting the functionality to work exactly as a ComboBox (or close enough anyway). :-)
Thank you so much for your helpful comments :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting a treeview inside a combobox is not the right approach, you need to implement your own custom control to achieve this, I have just completed my code to do a similar requirement on a table cell and have pasted it for reference in an earlier question, you can use that to create your own popup.

[Java FX8 TreeView in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042136/java-fx8-treeview-in-a-table-cell)