# JavaFX CheckBoxTree in popup of drop-down Button

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, treeview, antialiasing

In order for the end-user to constrain a search to some columns of the main TableView, I needed a treeview with checkboxes.
I decided to embed this TreeView in a popup, showing on click on a custom button.

I have created the following class, inspired from the question:
[Java FX8 TreeView in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042136/java-fx8-treeview-in-a-table-cell)

```
public class CustomTreeMenuButton extends MenuButton {
    private PopupControl popup = new PopupControl();
    private TreeView<? extends Object> tree;
    private CustomTreeMenuButton me = this;

    public void setTree(TreeView<? extends Object> tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
    }

    public CustomTreeMenuButton() {
        super();
        this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (!popup.isShowing()) {

                    Bounds b = me.localToScreen(me.getBoundsInLocal());
                    double x = b.getMinX();
                    double y = b.getMaxY();

                    popup.setAutoHide(true);
                    // popup.setAutoFix(true);
                    popup.setAnchorX(x);
                    popup.setAnchorY(y);

                    popup.setSkin(new Skin<Skinnable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void dispose() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Node getNode() {
                            return tree;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Skinnable getSkinnable() {
                            return null;
                        }
                    });

                    popup.show(me.getScene().getWindow());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The tree I am working with contains `CheckBoxTreeItem` objects, and while the popup is working, there is some weird blur on all checkboxes, whenever the focus is not on a checkbox. (See GIF below)

[image: CheckBoxTreeItem Blur]

First, I was thinking it was maybe an antialiasing problem, but `popup.getScene().getAntiAliasing().toString()` returns `DISABLED`

Then, I saw that non integer anchor points could cause problems. However `popup.setAutoFix(true)` did nothing, nor did the following:

```
popup.setAnchorX(new Double(x).intValue());
popup.setAnchorY(new Double(y).intValue());
```

It might be worth noting that I am working with FXML.

How can I get sharp checkboxes regardless of their focus ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a built-in control, [CustomMenuItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html), rather than reinventing the wheel:

> A MenuItem that allows for arbitrary nodes to be embedded within it,
>   by assigning a Node to the content property.

**An example**

```
// Create the tree
CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("All stuff");
rootItem.setExpanded(true);                  

final TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String>(rootItem);  
tree.setEditable(true);

tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());    
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    final CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem = 
            new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Stuff" + (i+1));
    rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);                
}

tree.setRoot(rootItem);
tree.setShowRoot(true);

// Create a custom menu item
CustomMenuItem customMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(tree);
customMenuItem.setHideOnClick(false);

// Create the menu button
MenuButton mb = new MenuButton("Stuffs");
mb.getItems().add(customMenuItem);
```

*And the output*

[image]

**Note:** It is important to set the [hideOnClickProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html#hideOnClickProperty%28%29) to `true`, to avoid closing when the user clicks in the tree, which can be even done in the contructor, so you can shorten the initialization to:

```
CustomMenuItem customMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(tree, false);
```

If you want to remove the hover glow, you can add the following CSS class:

```
.menu-item {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.
I just need to style the context menu of the button, to get rid of a weird hover glow, I guess.

Comment: Updated the answer for you about the hover glow.